# Dynamically fetch the JSON file and load it into grid using angularjs

Tags: json, angularjs

In the below code,I am trying to fetch the data from app.json to a grid using angular.js. Is it possible for me to dynamically fetch the json files instead of hard coding it in my code?

```
app.controller('MyCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
    $http.get('jsonfiles/app.json')
       .success(function (data) {
            $scope.myData = data;
   });
   $scope.gridOptions = { data: 'myData' };
});
```

Comment: Yes you can e.g. var fileName = "app.json''; $http.get('jsonfiles/'+fileName)

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you are using UI grid. I think you can set the data in success call back.

```
app.controller('MyCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
    $http.get('jsonfiles/app.json')
       .success(function (data) {
            $scope.myData = data;
            $scope.gridOptions = { data: 'myData' };
   });

});
```

Note that above snippet is just an example I am giving. Since I have not worked with the directive, I am not sure what is the exact syntax to do it.

Perhaps you can refer to jsfiddle example at http://jsfiddle.net/relly/ysmg1qkt/